# How to extend Silverstripe Blog module?

Tags: silverstripe-4

I'm looking a using Siverstripe's blog module for a project. The blog has most of the features I want, but as the site is mostly book focused I's like to add some fields to the blogpost table to hold book data (title, author, rating, etc. It seems like this should be relatively simple but I can't seem to get it to work. I've created the following extension PHP file:

```
namespace SilverStripe\Blog\Model;

use SilverStripe\Blog\Model\BlogPost;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextareaField;

class BookDataExtension extends BlogPost
{

    private static $db = [
        'bookTitle' => 'Varchar',
        'bookAuthor' => 'Varchar',
        'bookSeries' => 'Varchar',
        'bookISBN' => 'Varchar',
        'bookSeriesNum' => 'Int',
        'bookRating' => 'Decimal',
        'bookCover' => 'Varchar'
    ];

}
```

And added the following to the mysite.yml file:

```
SilverStripe\Blog\BlogPost:
  extensions:
    - SilverStripe\Blog\BookDataExtension
```

I also tried adding the above to the config.yml file for the blog module itself. However, no matter what I try, when I rebuild the system it creates *new* table(s) for BookDataExtension rather than adding the fields to the BlogPost table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you subclassed `BlogPost` instead of plugging an extension to it, aka. extending it...

Your `BlogPostExtension` has to subclass `DataExtension`; it can be in your own namespace:

```
namespace MyProject\Extensions;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;

class BookDataExtension extends DataExtension
{

    private static $db = [
        'bookTitle' => 'Varchar',
        'bookAuthor' => 'Varchar',
        'bookSeries' => 'Varchar',
        'bookISBN' => 'Varchar',
        'bookSeriesNum' => 'Int',
        'bookRating' => 'Decimal',
        'bookCover' => 'Varchar'
    ];

}
```

Then you can configure `BlogPost` to add your extension like you did before:

```
SilverStripe\Blog\BlogPost:
  extensions:
    - MyProject\Extensions\BookDataExtension
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It doesn't create new tables like it was doing, but it doesn't add the columns to the BlogPost table either. As far as I can tell, the extension code doesn't result in any DB changes.

Comment: did you run dev/build with a flush? Config is cached, so you need to flush it to take effect

Comment: Of course, I run that after every change to any file. I tried a few other things, but nothing is getting the columns added to the table.

Comment: does dev/build end with "done" ? maybe there's a small php error or typo somewhere causing problems.

Comment: No, it ends with "Database build complete!" even if I remove all my code.

Comment: is the YML file indented properly - using SPACES, not tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
    use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;

    class BookDataExtension extends DataExtension {

        private static $db = [
            'db_field_example' => 'Varchar'
        ];

        public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
            // Add fields here
        }

    }

}
```

add your extension to app/src/extensions/

and in your config:

```
SilverStripe\Blog\Model\BlogPost:
  extensions:
    - BookDataExtension
```